# С++ Что означает запись: float (*func4(double)(void))[10];?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Есть такая строка кода: `float (*func4(double)(void))[10];`  . Не могу понять, что это такое. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы нигде не ошиблись? потому как это не компилируется...

Comment: Это - бессмысленная "строка кода". Больше тут понимать нечего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func4` объявлено как функция с параметром `(double)`, возвращающая функцию без параметров, возвращающую указатель на массив `float [10]`.

С++ не позволяет функциям иметь тип возврата "функция". Поэтому данное объявление не является корректным.

Comment: А если запись будет такой: `float (*func4(double, void))[10];`?

Comment: @Настя Шпит: Это вообще белиберда. Параметров типа `void` быть не может. Допускается синтаксис `(void)`, но у такого синтаксиса свой зарезервированный смысл. А через запятую `void` использован быт не может.

Comment: большое спасибо.

Comment: Вы сами эту конструкцию разобрали или [с помощью cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=float+%28*func4%28double%29%28void%29%29%5B10%5D%3B)?

Comment: @Arhad: Я-то сам. Не все таки были (и еще есть) сомнения по поводу того, синтаксическая это ошибка или семантическая, а грамматику разбирать на пальцах лень. Потому я скормил это в GCC и получил, что "функция не может возвращать функцию". Это еще ничего не гарантирует, но все таки есть надежда, что с синтаксисом тут все в порядке.

Comment: Вот, кстати, связанное обсуждение: [C++ function returning function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31387238/2553424). А так, если не обращать внимание на явный запрет в стандарте, здесь не только с синтаксисом всё в порядке, но и с семантикой (тип функции автоматически преобразуется в тип указателя на функцию).

Comment: @Arhad: С синтаксисом тут вроде действительно все в порядке (глянул таки в грамматику). Но вот к чему вы привели здесь "тип функции автоматически преобразуется в тип указателя на функцию" - не ясно. Это справедливо для типов параметров (функция - в указатель на функцию, массив - в указатель на элемент), но не для типа возвращаемого значения. В типе возвращаемого значения тип "функция" и тип "массив" просто запрещен. Никакого преобразования.

Comment: ISO 14882 прямо отрицает возможность возврата функции и массива (11.3.5:10), а ISO 9899 четко указывает, что возвращаемое из функции должно иметь регистровый класс памяти (6.7.6.3:1,2).

Comment: @BwanaTheMaster 6.7.6.3 говорит, что `register` - это единственный класс памяти, который может быть использован с *параметрами* функции. Откуда вы взяли про "регистровый класс памяти *возвращаемого значения*", да еще и "четко указывает" и "должен" - не ясно.